# I get an Error: "Java.Net.SocketException" When i call the log in Api or the Register Api Using Web Api & Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, webapi

This is my Register Api:

public async Task RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
{

```
            var model = new RegisterBindingModel
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
            };

        try
        {

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://155.238.210.61:44382/api/Account/Register/", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oxception Occured" + ex);
        }
        return false;

    }
```

==================================================================================

My View Model:

public class RegisterViewModel
{
private readonly ApiServices _apiService = new ApiServices();

```
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ICommand RegisterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                var isSuccess = await _apiService.RegisterAsync(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
                Settings.Email = Email;
                Settings.Password = Password;

                //ClearFields();

                if (isSuccess)
                
                    Message = "Registered Successfully";
                    else
                    
                    Message = "Error Occured, Please try Again";
                   
            });
        }
    }

    
}
```

}

=========================================
Helper Class:

public static class Settings
{
private static ISettings AppSettings
{
get
{
return CrossSettings.Current;
}
}

```
    public static string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("Email", "");
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("Email", value);
        }
    }


    public static string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("Password", "");
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("Password", value);
        }
    }


    public static DateTime AccessTokenExpirationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("AccessTokenExpirationDate", DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("AccessTokenExpirationDate", value);
        }
    }



    public static string AccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault("AccessToken", "");
        }
        set
        {
            AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("AccessToken", value);
        }
    }
}
```

=========================
The Web Api is Connected to an Sql Server DB

Comment: Java.Net.SocketException” , what are the rest of the exception details? i.e. is it a security failure due to the fact that you are not using a secure transport (`https`)?

Comment: So basically, it Appears like: Exception Unhandled, then below: **Java.Net.SocketException:** 'Connection reset'

Comment: @SushiHangover  i hope i Answered u properly SushiHangover

Comment: At first, when i just used "localhost:44382" it gave me an Error that it cannot connect to localhost... I searched regarding the error n i was advised to Actually use my IP Address,  did that as u from my code

Comment: On the very same Web Api, When i Call the Log In And the Register Aip Using Postman, they All work perfect, And i can even Access Data From my Sql Server Db